# how to remove reflecting light on image imported as a plane?

Tags: light

[image: I want light to reflect only to a model(NOT AN IMAGE IMPORTED AS A PLANE)]

I want light to reflect only for a model(not for an image imported as a plane)

Comment: hello, it depends what you call reflecting light, you can either use an Emission shader instead of a Diffuse, or lower down the specular value, but please tell a bit more

Answer (score 3):

An Emission shader is propperly able to fix your problem. Here is how to do that:
[image]
Go into the shading window.

[image]
Delete the Principled BSDF shader.

[image]
Add an Emission shader.

[image]
Connect the shaders like on this image.

[image]
Now it should be working.

Answer (score 3):

The *Import Images as Planes* file selection window has an extensive set of options in a panel on the right. You may have to press <kbd>N</kbd> to reveal it.

Here are a few of them. One of the material options is 'Shadeless':

[image]

.. which produces the desired characteristics. It does it by using an 'IAP_SHADELESS' group:

[image]

..which is worth a look, if you want to see how these things work.

Comment: Absolutely this is the best options. Thank you.